# Why does .lesshst keep showing up in my ~

Tags: dotfiles

I never use `less`, and have always used `more`.  It is what I was introduced to, which is probably why I use `more` more instead of using `less` more. ( *Sorry, that is going to sound a bit of a mess :)* )

I just tried `less` and couldn't even quit out of it, until I realized it took a vi/vim style command.  At least, I believe that is what happened.

By in ~ there is always a `.lesshst` **file**, which I `rm` all the time, as I would prefer to use `more` or `nano` for simple stuff and I can use TextMate for simple text editing, or Sublime or whatever else I am in the mood for.

I also just noticed ".jbapps-myusername" is in ~ now as well.  This showed up 2 days ago, and I don't recall installing anything strange.  Any idea what it is?  I have never jailbroken my phone, and don't install hacks on my machine.  Those things that do go into that grey area are getting played with in a VM, not on the core of the machine I am working on as my main computer.

```
$file .jbapps-haneda 
.jbapps-haneda: ASCII text, with no line terminators
```

The contents of the `.jbapps-*` file are "483^@" with no leading or trailing newlines, carriage returns etc.

Then there is my git issue.  I have a `.config` directory, inside it is a "git" dir, which inside that is a file called "ignore", which as far as I can tell, is near identical to `.gitignore_global.`  Did git create `.config`, or is this a convention that other apps use as well?

That brings me to my final issue, in ~ I have .gitignore_global, .gitconfig, and also .config/git/ignore

Seems a mess to me, I would love to `mv .gitignore_global .gitconfig .config/git`
Is there a config somewhere that I can define these locations?  It's all just a mess of dot files, it would be so much nicer if ~ simply had `.config` and all the dot files were in there.  I can live with .ssh as it is a directory, so there is at least an effort to not litter my home dir.  But raw dot files kind of get in my way.  I know I can `ls -l` and not show the dot files, but I think seeing all your files all the time is a good way to learn what has been created that you might not be aware of.

Thank you.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

FIlenames starting with . are (lightly) hidden files. They're often use by programs to record configuration or usage information. Sometimes that's recorded from the last time you used the program; that's the case with [`less` and the `.lesshist` "history" file](https://web.archive.org/web/20141129223918/http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/less1.html).

If you aren't sure which program created the file, a websearch will usually answer the question... so I'm leaving understanding the rest of those files as an Exercise For The Reader.

Comment: And I take it there is no system level config that says "`store dot files: ~/.config`" or similar, to take away some of the mess, with perhaps over-rides to "`store specific files: ~`"?  Spring is near, and I am looking to clean house :)

Comment: Unfortunately, each application decides where it wants to keep its own configuration. There are several conventions for this, but the home directory is one of the standard locations.

Comment: How would I go about finding what app used less, it was not me. I am tempted to chmod it so it can't run, but I have a feeling some installer scripts may rely on it, which I find crazy, they should use a conned than can only be configured by flags, not some config file that will fail if it is not just as they had theirs.

Comment: One command that uses `less` is `man`. If you use `more`, you've probably used `man` as well, hence `. lesshst` existence.

Comment: Broken link `An error has been encountered in accessing this page. `

Answer (score 11):

You can disable the creation of the `~/.lesshst` file by setting the `LESSHISTFILE` variable to `-`.

```
export LESSHISTFILE=-
```

You can also set the above to another valid file path to have the `less` command use  that file instead. I like to do the following in my `~/.zprofile` (`~/.profile` for non-zsh users) file:

```
export LESSHISTFILE="$XDG_STATE_HOME"/less/history
```

---

As for your `git` stuff, `Git` probably wasn't the program that created the `~/.config` folder. That folder is part of the XDG Base Dirs [specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html), and `git` actually [respects](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) this specification. In short all you need to do is:

- `mv -T ~/.gitconfig $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config`
- `mv -T ~/.gitignore_global $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore`

Also see [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_Base_Directory) for XDG Base Directory

---

Finally, for the other files you notice, unfortunately many developers are not aware of where to put various files, so they end up just using the hidden folder/files method to place stuff in the user's home directory. The [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Base_Directory#Hardcoded) actually has a section that tracks these things. Feel free to report any programs you find that are misusing the hidden folder/files trick.

Comment: For example in `~/.bashrc`, see also https://askubuntu.com/questions/386311/how-can-i-stop-less-from-storing-history

Comment: Just noting here that per the spec, XDG_STATE_HOME would be more appropriate for history files: "$XDG_STATE_HOME ... may contain: actions history (logs, history, recently used files, …)"

Comment: @JakeRomer this is my first time hearing of `XDG_STATE_HOME`. Is that new?

Comment: I think it's relatively a new addition — I can't find a changelog for the spec but I notice that the rust-xdg library only recently added support for it and hasn't released it yet.

Comment: How do I disable in Windows?

Answer (score 8):

A .lesshst file will be generated in one’s home directory if one uses the `man` command to view documentation; performs a search within such documentation by using the <kbd>/</kbd> key, typing a search term, and pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to begin a search; and subsequently exits the `man` command documentation using the <kbd>q</kbd> key.

Apparently, one can use the data in this file to perform a `man` command search using the last used search term the next time one uses the `man` command to view documentation. (This would be accomplished by pressing the search key combinations <kbd>N</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> after having generated a .lesshst file.) It's not clear to me what the benefit of storing search terms preceding the last is though.

Answer (score 3):

I just looked into that this morning. Because of my OCD, I wanted to move the .lesshst file from my `$HOME` and put it in my `$XDG_LOG_HOME`.

## For less:

I created a lesskey-file in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` called "lesskey", in this lesskey-file, I set the LESSHISTFILE environment variable to the path of my future less-history-file (in `$XDG_LOG_HOME`). If you already have a lesskey just add to it.
Then in my zshrc (or bashrc) I set the following line :

`alias less='less --lesskey-file=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/lesskey'`

That does the trick only when using less

## For man:

I put the following line in my zshrc (or bashrc):

`alias man='man --pager="less --lesskey-file=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/lesskey"'`

That does the trick with man !
I tried to use more but it does not seem to generate a .lesshst in $HOME

Comment: Any advantage using this approach over directly setting `LESSHISTFILE` in `~/.profile` or similar?

Comment: What is `XDG_LOG_HOME`? It appears to be non-standard

Answer (score 1):

You may be using `less` without knowing it. From the `man` page:

```
COMPATIBILITY WITH MORE
   If the environment variable LESS_IS_MORE is set to 1, or if the program is invoked via a file link
   named "more", less behaves (mostly) in conformance with the POSIX  "more"  command  specification.
   In this mode, less behaves differently in these ways:

   The  -e  option  works differently.  If the -e option is not set, less behaves as if the -E option
   were set.  If the -e option is set, less behaves as if the -e and -F options were set.

   The -m option works differently.  If the -m option is not set, the medium prompt is used,  and  it
   is prefixed with the string "--More--".  If the -m option is set, the short prompt is used.

   The  -n  option  acts  like the -z option.  The normal behavior of the -n option is unavailable in
   this mode.

   The parameter to the -p option is taken to be a less command rather than a search pattern.

   The LESS environment variable is ignored, and the MORE environment variable is used in its place.
```

Answer (score 0):

Command `git config --list` use  program LESS.